# Counting weighted score in MySQL - star rating and votes

Tags: php, mysql

I have posts rated with stars, in a 1-to-5 scale. I would like to sort the posts by rating, **including** the factor of votes number (let's call it - popularity).

I know similar questions were asked before, but I don't see a clear solution. Would be perfect to get to know a formula that can be used for this purpose, as well as it's MySQL equivalent.

Examples below will hopefully explain what I need:

- (5 stars, 1 vote) `<` (4 stars, 3 votes)
- (4 stars, 1 vote) `<` (3 stars, 12 votes)
- (1 star, 345 votes) `<` (2 stars, 5 votes)

Does anyone have experience in solving this problem? I already tried some simple formulas (like **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512613/mysql-rating-with-weight)**), but they fail to "recognize" that the circumstances are different in the set of **[5, 2.5]** and **(2.5, 0]**. I think that the function to use could be logarithmic, but I can't seem to get to it the proper way.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: It makes senser that `(1 star, 345 votes) < (2 stars, 5 votes)`, but what rules do you want to have for the other ones? Think about the logic first before thinking in terms of PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Something as simple as adding some weights to each of the star count would work, I'd say.

I've created a simple table:

```
╔════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ Id ║ Name   ║ Stars3 ║ Stars2 ║ Stars1 ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ 1  ║ Item 1 ║ 1      ║ 0      ║ 0      ║
║ 2  ║ Item 2 ║ 0      ║ 1      ║ 2      ║
║ 3  ║ Item 3 ║ 0      ║ 2      ║ 5      ║
║ 4  ║ Item 4 ║ 4      ║ 0      ║ 2      ║
╚════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Basically, *StarsX* shows the amount of the specific star.

What I do then, think of some random number for making it *fair-ish*.

- 3 stars is worth 5 points;
- 2 stars is worth 2 points;
- 1 star is worth 1 point;

Now, a simple query to get the total score:

```
SELECT *,(stars3*5+stars2*2+stars1) as total_score FROM `posts_with_scores`
```

And I get this:

```
╔════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ Id ║ Name   ║ Stars3 ║ Stars2 ║ Stars1 ║ Total Score ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1  ║ Item 1 ║ 1      ║ 0      ║ 0      ║ 5           ║
║ 2  ║ Item 2 ║ 0      ║ 1      ║ 2      ║ 4           ║
║ 3  ║ Item 3 ║ 0      ║ 2      ║ 5      ║ 9           ║
║ 4  ║ Item 4 ║ 4      ║ 0      ║ 2      ║ 22          ║
╚════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

A [similar system was sometimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_medal_table#Weighted_ranking) used by news papers and such to calculate the *score* of countries based on the medals they received. Something like 3 points for a gold medal, 2 points for a silver medal and a point for a bronze medal.

Comment: I was thinking about it, although my table structure is not this convenient ;) It's a pivot table with `post_id`, `user_id`, and `vote` (being a number between 1-5). Still doable of course, so I will surely try it.

Comment: You'd just have to do a join to calculate the score. Should not be too hard!