# How do I normalize stock ratings with number of analysts and their ratings with weight given to number of entries?

Tags: math

I am trying to consolidate Analyst ratings for a given stock. Factors to consider are the actual ratings, number of analysts so that I can compare the
same stock quarter to quarter and compare one stock to another.

I selected Buy = 5 and Sell = 1 and the rest in-between. Using the formula Sum ( rating * number of analysts gave that rating) to get score. Is that be the right approach?

I want to give weight to how many analysts are following the stock as well.

Thank you for your help.

I found one formula on StackOverflow but mathematically is that a good approach?

[MySQL Rating With Weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512613/mysql-rating-with-weight)

Comment: Maybe this is not a good question for Stack Overflow, but rather Statistics or Quantitative Finance Stackexchange

Comment: Ok, will wait for a couple of hours and delete the question/close the question.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested this may not be the right question for Math. I apologize. In any case, I used bayesian to calculate the score using this thread:

[How to balance number of ratings versus the ratings themselves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495509/how-to-balance-number-of-ratings-versus-the-ratings-themselves)

Even then I realized I can't compare one stock to another as the number of analysts vary, their quality varies so just comparing the same stock from quarter to quarter to see the change. Please consider this as closed.